# No compile errors in my code, but no output

Tags: java

I am very new at this. I am sure the error is with my arrays. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. When I run it, it allows for me to enter the letter grades and credit hours, but I do not get any output.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Calculating gpa
 * 
 * @author Brooklyn
 * @version1 11/15/2016
 *
 */

public class CalculateGPA {
    /**
     *
     * Entry point for the program javadoc
     *
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // declare vars

        // input: prompt user to enter letter grade and credit hours
        System.out.println("What are your letter grades?");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String x = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("How many credit hours are you taking?");
        int v = input.nextInt();
        int[] creditHours = new int[v];
        for (int i = 0; i < creditHours.length; i++) {
            creditHours[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        char[] letterGrade = x.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < letterGrade.length; i++) {
            letterGrade[i] = input.next().charAt(i);
        }

        // Processing: calculate gpa
        double gpa = calculateGpa(letterGrade, creditHours);
    }
    // output: display GPA
    // displayGPA(gpa);

    /** Method calculates GPA */
    public static double calculateGpa(char[] letterGrade, int[] creditHours) {
        int totalQuality = 0;
        int numericGrade;
        double gpa = 0.0;

        // double qualityPoint = 4 * creditHours[0];
        if (letterGrade.equals("A")) {
            numericGrade = 4;
            totalQuality += numericGrade;

        } else if (letterGrade.equals("B")) {
            numericGrade = 3;
            totalQuality += numericGrade;

        } else if (letterGrade.equals("C")) {
            numericGrade = 2;
            totalQuality += numericGrade;

        } else if (letterGrade.equals("D")) {
            numericGrade = 1;
            totalQuality += numericGrade;

        } else if (letterGrade.equals("F")) {
            numericGrade = 0;
            totalQuality += numericGrade;
        }

        int totalHours = creditHours[0];
        gpa = totalQuality / totalHours;
        return totalQuality / totalHours;
    }

    public static void displayGPA(double gpa) {
        System.out.println("Overall GPA is" + gpa);

    }

}
```

Comment: You never call `displayGPA`. That's the issue.

Comment: Okay I fixed it. I had commented it out because I couldnt get it run, but I was trying to call that function outside the main method. However, I still am not getting output.

Comment: Please update the code in your question with the call to `displayGPA`.

Answer (score 0):

Call this function in your main method. displayGPA("GPA Is" + gpa);

Comment: Okay, I fixed that. I was trying to call it, but had it outside the main method so I just commented it out. But I am still not getting any output.

Answer (score 0):

For your understanding, I have modified your existing code which calculates the GPA correctly.

My code takes into account the credit hours associated with the grade.

Say for example you got A in course which had 1 credit hours and B in course which had 5 credit hours. 
Therefore, your GPA would be for each course (credit hours * grade value) / (credit hours) 
In this case, `(1 * 4 + 5 * 3) / (1 + 5) = 3.16`

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CalculateGPA {
private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // get number of courses
    System.out.println("How many courses have you taken ?");
    int n = input.nextInt();

    // get grades for those courses
    char letterGrade[] = new char[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println("What are your letter grades for course " + (i + 1));
        String g = input.next();
        letterGrade[i] = g.charAt(0);
    }

    // get credit hours associated with those courses
    int creditHours[] = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println(
                "Enter credit hours for your course number: " + (i + 1) + " where you got " + letterGrade[i]);
        creditHours[i] = input.nextInt();
    }

    // Processing: calculate gpa
    double gpa = calculateGpa(letterGrade, creditHours);
    // output: display GPA
    displayGPA(gpa);
}

/** Method calculates GPA */
public static double calculateGpa(char[] letterGrade, int[] creditHours) {

    // formula: (gradeValue1 * creditHours1 + gradeValue2 * creditHours2 + ... ) / (creditHours1 + creditHours2 + ...) 

    int totalQuality = 0;
    int creditHoursTotal = 0;
    double gpa = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < letterGrade.length; i++) {
        switch (letterGrade[i]) {
        case 'A':
            totalQuality += 4 * creditHours[i];
            creditHoursTotal += creditHours[i];
            break;
        case 'B':
            totalQuality += 3 * creditHours[i];
            creditHoursTotal += creditHours[i];
            break;
        case 'C':
            totalQuality += 2 * creditHours[i];
            creditHoursTotal += creditHours[i];
            break;
        case 'D':
            totalQuality += 1 * creditHours[i];
            creditHoursTotal += creditHours[i];
            break;
        case 'F':
            // zero score and so there will be no impact on totalQuality
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid letter");
            break;
        }
    }

    gpa = (double) totalQuality / creditHoursTotal;
    return gpa;
}

public static void displayGPA(double gpa) {
    System.out.println("Overall GPA = " + gpa);

}

}
```

> Sample run
>   How many courses have you taken ?
>   2
>   What are your letter grades for course 1
>   A
>   What are your letter grades for course 2
>   B
>   Enter credit hours for your course number: 1 where you got A
>   1
>   Enter credit hours for your course number: 2 where you got B
>   5
>   Overall GPA = 3.1666666666666665